# Does Ethereum 2.0 have privacy on state variables?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I know in 1.x state values were visible to anyone on the network. With the release of 2.0, is there still no privacy? Also I understand 2.0 is being released in phases. Is there a timetable with the relevant points about privacy?

Answer (score 0):

No,

However, the primitives exist in order to be able to build privacy-preserving applications on top of Ethereum, such as [Tornado Cash](https://github.com/tornadocash/tornado-core). Also see https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-roadmap/privacy/